# How to use ax.view_init(azim=, elev =) to see a 3D plot in the zy plane?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying different variations of changing the azimuthal and elevation angles to see the zy-plane, i.e. the z-axis being along the typical x-axis, y-axis being as it is, and the x-axis now pointing into the page.

I believe this would be possible if I could do the azimuthal and elevation angle rotations in pieces (so rotating 90 degrees in elevation first, then 90 in azimuthal) but using this line doesn't work:
 `ax.view_init(azim = 90, elev = 90)`

I've also tried different combinations and tried using 270 as well but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see your full code to understand why it's not working. While your syntax for the `view_init` function is correct, it's difficult to say what's causing the problem without a broader context.

Here's some sample code with a 3d plane to try it out for yourself. Do you still get the same error here? If yes, it might be a versioning issue

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# define coefficients for 3d plane : ax + by + c
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10, 10, 50), np.linspace(-10, 10, 50))
z = (-a * x - b * y - c) / 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# plot the surface with black color
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='black')
ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=60) # put whatever you want here

ax.set_title('3D Plane Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')

plt.show()
```